# Error when trying to split XML file using XML::LibXML module

Tags: xml, perl, xpath, xml-libxml

I have been trying to split XML data using the [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML::LibXML) module, but it throws an error like this

```
Can't call method "findnodes" without a package or object reference
```

My input

```
<xml>
  <bhap id="1">
    <label>cylind - I</label>
    <title>premier</title>
    <rect id="S1">
      <title>Short</title>
      <label>1.</label>
      <p><text>welcome</text></p>
    </rect>
    <rect id="S2">
      <title>Definite</title>
      <label>2.</label>
      <p><text>welcome1</text></p>
    </rect>
  </bhap>
  <bhap id="2">
    <label>cylind – II</label>
    <title>AUTHORITIES AND ITS EMPLOYEES</title>
    <rect id="S3">
      <title>nauty.&#x2014;</title>
      <label>3.</label>
      <p><text>welcome3</text></p>
    </rect>
    <rect id=S4">
      <title>Term</title>
      <label>4.</label>
      <p><text>welcome4</text></p>
    </rect>
  </bhap>
</xml>
```

output needed

file 1

```
<xml>
  <bhap id="1">
    <label>cylind - I</label>
    <title>premier</title>
    <rect id="S1">
      <title>Short</title>
      <label>1.</label>
      <p><text>welcome</text></p>
    </rect>
  </bhap>
</xml>
```

file 2

```
<xml>   
  <bhap id="1">
    <label>cylind - I</label>
    <title>premier</title>
    <rect id="S2">
      <title>Definite</title>
      <label>2.</label>
      <p><text>welcome1</text></p>
    </rect>
  </bhap>
</xml>
```

file 3

```
<xml>
  <bhap id="2">
    <label>cylind – II</label>
    <title>AUTHORITIES AND ITS EMPLOYEES</title>
    <rect id="S3">
      <title>nauty.&#x2014;</title>
      <label>3.</label>
      <p><text>welcome3</text></p>
    </rect>
  </bhap>
</xml>
```

file 4

```
<xml>       
  <bhap id="2">
    <label>cylind – II</label>
    <title>AUTHORITIES AND ITS EMPLOYEES</title>
    <rect id=S4">
      <title>Term</title>
      <label>4.</label>
      <p><text>welcome4</text></p>
    </rect>
  </bhap>
</xml>
```

my code

```
use XML::LibXML;

my $file   = shift || die "usage $0 <xmlfile>";
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $doc    = $parser->parse_file($file);

my @nodes = $doc->findnodes('//bhap');
foreach my $node1 (@nodes) {

    my $bhap = $node1->toString(), "\n";

    if ( $bhap =~ m/(<bhap.+?>.+?<\/title>)(.+?)(<\/bhap>)/is ) {

        my $bhap1 = $1;
        my $bhap2 = $2;
        my $bhap3 = $3;

        my $nodes1 = $bhap->findnodes('//rect');
        foreach my $node (@$nodes1) {

            my $rect = $node->toString();

            if ( $rect =~ m/(<rect\s*id="(.+?)">.+?<\/rect>)/is ) {

                my $var1 = $1;
                my $var2 = $2;

                print "file" $var2;
                print "<xml>" print $bhap1;
                print $var1;
                print $bhap3;
                print "</xml>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is xml_split an option: http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Twig/tools/xml_split/xml_split

Comment: You assign to `$bhap` etc. then read from `$bhap`. Using `use warnings; use strict;` catches this sort of thing.

Comment: `my $nodes1 = $bhap->findnodes('//rect');` You're calling `findnodes` on a string here.

Comment: I had a script that was working for more than a year, and just started throwing this. Something changed in the machine's perl or package installation? Irksome.

Answer (score 2):

OK, so you start out well, but then ... fall in to the 'regular expression' trap. XML is not a good thing to parse with regular expressions, because it's just too complicated - do do it well you need to handle/validate tag nestings, and line feeds and all sorts of things that basically just make your regular expression a brittle piece of code. So please don.

But most importantly of all - ALWAYS use `strict` and `warnings` prior to posting queries. These are your first port of call for troubleshooting.

If you did you would see things like:

```
print "file" $var2;
```

That's not going to work - at all. There's a bunch of others that aren't going to work properly in 'your code' so really - that would be the starting point.

Also - your XML isn't valid - your 'S4' I think is missing a quote mark.

Anyway, assuming that's just a typo, I'd start with [`XML::Twig`](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/XML-Twig-3.48/Twig.pm) (because I understand it better than LibXML rather than any specific reason) and do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my %children_of;

#as we process, extract all the 'rect' elements - along with a reference to their context.
sub process_rect {
    my ( $twig, $rect ) = @_;
    push( @{ $children_of{ $rect->parent } }, $rect->cut );
}


my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
    'pretty_print'  => 'indented',
    'twig_handlers' => { 'rect' => \&process_rect },

);

$twig->parse( \*DATA );

#run through all the 'bhap' elements. 
foreach my $bhap ( $twig->root->children('bhap') ) {
    #find the rect elements under this bhap. 
    foreach my $rect ( @{ $children_of{$bhap} } ) {
        #create a new XML document - copy the 'root' name from your original document. 
        my $xml    = XML::Twig::Elt->new( $twig -> root -> name );
        #duplicate this 'bhap' element by copying it, rather than cutting it,
        #so we can paste it more than once (e.g. per 'rect')
        my $subset = $bhap->copy;
        #insert the 'bhap' into our new xml. 
        $subset->paste( last_child => $xml );
        #insert our cut rect beneath this bhap. 
        $rect->paste( last_child => $subset );

        #print the resulting XML. 
        print "--\n";
        $xml->print;
    }
}

__DATA__
<xml>

<bhap id="1">
                <label>cylind - I</label>
                <title>premier</title>
                <rect id="S1">
                    <title>Short</title>
                    <label>1.</label>
                    <p><text>welcome</text></p>
                </rect>
                <rect id="S2">
                    <title>Definite</title>
                    <label>2.</label>
                    <p><text>welcome1</text></p>
                </rect>
        </bhap>
            <bhap id="2">
                <label>cylind - II</label>
                <title>AUTHORITIES AND ITS EMPLOYEES</title>

                <rect id="S3">
                    <title>nauty.&#x2014;</title>
                    <label>3.</label>
                    <p><text>welcome3</text></p>
                </rect>

                <rect id="S4">
                    <title>Term</title>
                    <label>4.</label>
                    <p><text>welcome4</text></p>
                </rect></bhap>

</xml>
```

We preprocess the XML, and 'snip out' the `rect` nodes. Then we cycle through each of the `bhap` nodes - copying them, and inserting the relevant `rect` beneath them.

This gives output of:

```
--
<xml>
  <bhap id="1">
    <label>cylind - I</label>
    <title>premier</title>
    <rect id="S1">
      <title>Short</title>
      <label>1.</label>
      <p>
        <text>welcome</text>
      </p>
    </rect>
  </bhap>
</xml>
--
<xml>
  <bhap id="1">
    <label>cylind - I</label>
    <title>premier</title>
    <rect id="S2">
      <title>Definite</title>
      <label>2.</label>
      <p>
        <text>welcome1</text>
      </p>
    </rect>
  </bhap>
</xml>
--
<xml>
  <bhap id="2">
    <label>cylind - II</label>
    <title>AUTHORITIES AND ITS EMPLOYEES</title>
    <rect id="S3">
      <title>nauty.â€”</title>
      <label>3.</label>
      <p>
        <text>welcome3</text>
      </p>
    </rect>
  </bhap>
</xml>
--
<xml>
  <bhap id="2">
    <label>cylind - II</label>
    <title>AUTHORITIES AND ITS EMPLOYEES</title>
    <rect id="S4">
      <title>Term</title>
      <label>4.</label>
      <p>
        <text>welcome4</text>
      </p>
    </rect>
  </bhap>
</xml>
```

Which looks at least *fairly* close to what you're trying to produce. I've skipped over reading in files and printing out the content, because reconstructing the XML is the harder part.

I would also suggest looking at [`xml_split`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Twig/tools/xml_split/xml_split) which is available with `XML::Twig` as that might do exactly what you want anyway.

Comment: I'm sure that's all good advice, but the stated problem is the error "Can't call method "findnodes" without a package or object reference" and you've said nothing at all about that.